# Taking granular backup rather than complete site backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, backup, restore

When ever I want to move site to one server to another I take backup using "backup-spsite" command. This was fine until now so is there a way to take backup of those items which were changed?
For e.g. I make changes in a list and a page and only want to restore than on new server rather than complete site. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Central Administration, navigate to Backup and restore and select Export a site or a list.

[image]

... and navigate to the list or site you want to backup.

[image]

To recover, use PowerShell command [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) (even for lists)

```
# Importing customer list details

Import-SPWeb http://sharepoint-journey.com -path c:\backup\Customers.cmp -updateversions overwrite
```

Reference: [Backup and Restore in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2013-part1.html)