# Script to import a CSV file to a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, form, import

My organisation has an old SharePoint2010 website. The employees have used this site to fill a form to subscribe to some courses. Now a new version of this form is created in a new SharePoint2010 website. I'm search for a script to import a csv file to sharePoint List. In My case The old form has been exported into a csv file now i need to import this CSV  to the new list using a script. I am searching i don't find nothing yet!
Thank you.

Comment: What's the data that you need specifically migrate is it a specific list ??

Comment: data stored in the SharePoint List, is the List columns /structure same on source and destination farm.

Comment: Hi Warqas , thank you for your answer. I have to import all the data that are saved in the old form. All fields on the old form must be imported to the new form.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, provided that you have the same content type in the old list as the new one. If you do, it's fairly straight forward to use PowerShell, to read each item in the old list, and add it to the new list. You would however lose the created by, created, changed by, changed and author column value if you do. But if that's not an issue, you can find numerous of scripts online doing just that.

One would think that this new list was created in the wrong way if you where to keep the old records in the old list. One could build a complementary NewForm.aspx to accommodate the new features. But reading between lines, this isn't the case, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Benny, Your answer makes sense. I will continue my search with your suggestions

Comment: Hi benny am still stuck with the import. Both Libraries have the same content type. Still can't find a script to do that. Do you have any link for me?

Comment: @djgibbs Sure! Check out http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/76591/6382

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. This option will create a new list. I want to import the items from the old list to an existing one in the new SP Site!

Answer (score 1):

You can export the list from the old site as a template including the content and then bring it over to the new site. This way you will have your list settings as well as all the content as it was on the old site. I am not sure how this will tie in with the workflow but if the workflow is on the new site as well you should be able to associate it with the new list once you create it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. This option will create a new list. I want to import the items from the old list to an existing one in the new SP Site!